# How it is possible to multicharacter string the value of this string.length is 2?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make recursive function to reverse an array.
With argument ["h","e","l","l","o"], I got a string "olleh" with length 2, and unexpected result after transforming it to array. 
Could someone help with this situation? Why the string "olleh" has length 2.

```
let reverseString = function(s) {

if(s.length == 1) return s[0];

if(s.length > 1) {
return (s.pop() + reverseString(s)).split('');  
}  
}
```

I'm confused with this situation, and cann't figure out what is wrong...

```
reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]); //outputs ["o", "l", ",", "l", ",", 
",", ",", "e", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", ",", "h"]
```

if I change return value

```
return (s.pop() + reverseString(s)) ;
reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]); //outputs  string olleh
```

but the length of the string is strange:

```
return (s.pop() + reverseString(s)).length ;
reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]); //outputs 2
```

Comment: For one, why not just `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'].reverse()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively Reverse the Elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006064/recursively-reverse-the-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: @olkov interesting question. It may look like you just don't know about array.reverse() function, but maybe you do. In any case, if you wanna build your own function, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing type coercion there in your return value.

For one, why not just use `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'].reverse()`? That reverses an array right away.

---

But let's say you want to do this your way.

For one, your method takes an array and returns a string. Which means recursion will not work as expected, as sometimes it'll get different type of arguments.

What happens is this (I'm shortening it to just 3 characters, where it starts failing):

### Step 1: you give in ['h', 'e', l'].

Current State: we hold on to the `l` (`s.pop()`) here. We call `reverseString(['h', 'e'])`;

### Step 2: we give in ['h', 'e']

Current state:

- outer function still holds `l`.
- new function now holds `e` (from the new `s.pop()`)

### Step 3. we give in ['h']

Current state:

- outer function (step 1) still holds `l`.
- step 2 function holds `e`
- the third function returns `h` as a string.

### Step 4: add together two args: string `'e'` and an array `['h']`

Why that array? Because we added that `.split()` there at the end.

So in JavaScript, adding `'e' + ['h']` gives us 'eh'.

Still good, but by accident.

### Step 5: add together string `l` (from step 1) and the array that we get when we split 'eh' (meaning: `'l' + 'eh'.split('')`, which goes into `'le,h'`.

### Step 6: return the split of the string now.

If you go with more steps, you get way more of those unexpected splits. So take care of that split or simply use [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I understand where was a mistake.
Code below works:

```
var reverseString = function(s) {
if(s.length == 1) return s[0];

if(s.length > 1) {
return s.pop().split().concat(reverseString(s));  //all arrays and properly concatenated 
  }   
}
```

P.S. Of course there are many ways to reverse an array and this one is not the best )).

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you are returning the output, `(s.pop() + reverseString(s))` gives back the string `"eh"`, that's why you are seeing an output of 2 for the length.

Also, as mentioned by @Zlatko, you can also simply use the `.reverse()` method if you wanted to (and add a `.join("")` if you wanted to get the string back instead of the reversed array).

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseString(str){
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

console.log(reverseString("this is my string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing recursive calls, as an example, this is the sequence you will get from using `["b", "y", "e"]` as input when trying to get the length with `return (s.pop() + reverseString(s)).length;`

```
reverseString(["b","y","e"]) =>
return ("e" + reverseString(["b","y"]).length =>
return ("e" + return ("y" + reverseString(["b"])).length ).length =>
(*) return ("e" + return ("y" + "b").length ).length =>
(*) return ("e" + return 2).length =>
return ("e" + 2).length =>
return ("e2").length =>
return 2
```

Particularly, note what's happen when you reach the `end condition` (lines marked with `(*)`). Thats why you get `2` as output. If you want to get the length of the final reversed string, just access it after you have reversed your array:

```js
let reverseString = function(s)
{
    if (s.length <= 1) return s[0];
    return s.pop() + reverseString(s);
}

console.log("reversed:", reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]));
console.log("length:", reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]).length);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Anyway, note there is an [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method you can use:

```js
let reverseString = function(s)
{
    return s.slice().reverse().join("");
}

console.log("reversed:", reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"]));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Here, [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is used to avoid mutation of the `input`, since:

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array **in place**. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.